# truecrypt mounting through windows service

Tags: windows, services, interactive, truecrypt

I've created a windows service which silently mounts truecrypt volumes via command line. A couple issues have arose however; although the volume mounts correctly it won't show up in windows explorer unless I open truecrypt and manually click "refresh drive letters". Second, I keep randomly getting messages saying that Windows intereactive services has detected a dialog, and if I accept it will show truecrypt in some alternate desktop. What should I do to fix these issues?

Comment: "if I accept it will show truecrypt in some alternate desktop"  Screenshots?

Comment: @CountMurphy When badly written services try to show dialogs, you get this message (it's a Vista and newer feature for security).

Answer (score 0):

You are running into [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation), where all UI elements from a Windows Service are shown on the "alternate desktop" you came across. The [Interactive Services dialog can be disabled](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#DisableInteractiveServicesDialog), but think it through before doing so.

Are you running your service in a regular user account? And is it the main TrueCrypt window that is coming up?